# javascript regexp backreferences in character class possible?

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

Does javascript regular expressions support backreferences inside character class?

I want to do something like this:

```
htmlString.replace(/attribute_name=(['"])[^\1]*\1/,'')
```

But that does not work. This does:

```
htmlString.replace(/attribute_name=(['"])[^'"]*\1/,'')
```

Unfortunatelly my attribute_name can contain apostrophes or quotes, so I need to exlude the actual quoting character from the inside of the attribute, but leave the other one. 
I can't be sure which one is used. I can safely assume that quotes are in form of entity, but still there can be apostrophes inside:

```
<div attribute_name="John's car" class="someClass"></div>
<div attribute_name='some &quot;quoted text&quot;' class="someClass"></div>
```

I am not able to predict which of " or ' will be used around the attribute.

How to get rid of the attribute and leave the class attribute alone (not cut too much)?

context:
I am getting the html by $('templateContainer').innerHTML . I have to modify that html before inserting it into the page again. I have to cut some non-standard attibutes and all the ID attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be a LOT better off using DOM or some other actual model designed for hierarchical content. That said, if you *must* use regex, the simplest way would probably be to just use a `|` (OR) instead.

```
htmlString.replace(/attribute_name=('[^']*'|"[^"]*")/,'')
```

Comment: Yeah, simplest solutions are hardest to find.
I know it would be better to use DOM, but i need to do this before I put it back in DOM. It is a result of previous mistake in project and I have to little time to redesign it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers in that I don't think that the attributes are the place to do this type of thing, but I'm also wary of recommending the DOM either.  I just feel dirty when I do that, I don't know why.

I usually will try to use a javascript object to store my data in and then reference it using well-formed keys, etc.  *shrug*  It's more work, but it's cleaner IMHO.  But, it definitely isn't the only way to accomplish the task.

As to your question, you could also use the non-greedy matching in JavaScript and it would look like this:

```
htmlString.replace(/ ?attribute_name=(['"]).*?\1/, '')
```

[Regular Expressions in JavaScript | evolt.org](http://www.evolt.org/node/36435)